# How does the following syntax may be shortened and improved?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, optimization, syntax

Given a 12 x 13 matrix in Matlab, I need to select the row with the greatest value in column 9, every two rows, and create a matrix containing the selected rows. The following piece of code does the job, but I was wondering how this syntax could be improved and shortened.

```
A = rand(12,13);

a = A(1:2,:);
if a(1,9) > a(2,9)
    a = A(1,:);
else   
    a = A(2,:);
end

b = A(3:4,:);
if b(1,9) > b(2,9)
    b = A(3,:);
else
    b = A(4,:);
end

c = A(5:6,:);
if c(1,9) > c(2,9)
    c = A(5,:);
else
    c = A(6,:);
end

d = A(7:8,:);
if d(1,9) > d(2,9)
    d = A(7,:);
else
    d = A(8,:);
end

e = A(9:10,:);
if e(1,9) > e(2,9)
    e = A(9,:);
else
    e = A(10,:);
end

f = A(11:12,:);
if f(1,9) > f(2,9)
    f = A(11,:);
else
    f = A(12,:);
end

SELECTED_A = [a;b;c;d;e;f];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide a way shorter solution, but if you want it fully vectorized, you'll have to wait for someone with a little more proficiency. Here's the code:

```
A=rand(12,13);
B=zeros(6,13); % preallocate solutionarray
for ii=2:2:12 % loop through every (second) row
   [~,ind]=max([A(ii,9),A(ii-1,9)]); % check which element is greater
   B(ii/2,:)=A(ii-(ind==2),:); % select corresponding row
end
```

This will give you an array `B` with the values you are looking for.

EDIT: There was a little flaw in the code: the condition in row 5 of the code needs to be `ind==2` otherwise it will always chose the row with the smaller entry in column 9. Alternatively you could also leave it `ind==1` and switch the elements in row 4 i.e. `max([A(ii-1,9),A(ii,9)])`

Comment: The OP needs the _rows_, `SELECTED_A` is a 6x13 matrix.

Comment: No problem. `max` returns the index as second return value. Use that to select the desired row.

Comment: Shouldn't `[ind,~]` be `[~, ind]`? :)

Comment: @Jørgen Yes, and sorry for all those mistakes, I was just excited that i finally saw a question I could actually answer!